# Printing HTML javascript code inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, adsense

I have such an Adsense code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-12345";
/* my advertisement */
google_ad_slot = "2345";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

I have such an js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var adsenseCode='<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-12345";
    /* my advertisement */
    google_ad_slot = "2345";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>';

 $().append(adsenseCode);
}
```

I tried with double quotes, single quotes, removing comment lines etc. Not found the solution.
How can I print javascript code inside my HTML page?

Comment: Don't `document.write` after the page has loaded. It will replace the page contents with the written contents. You should be `write`ing in a script tag.

Comment: Why do you want to add this with javascript? This should be added to the html page itself as normal js tags. Adding them inside jQuery will cause some problems. First of all they might not be executed after injecting to the DOM.

Comment: @Zefiryn I normally I add adsense code while constructing the page. But some of my pages has some dynamic parts where I don't know exact result beforehand. So I ad after document load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like the following should do the trick...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var adsenseCode='<script type="text/javascript">  \
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-12345";  \
    /* my advertisement */   \
    google_ad_slot = "2345"; \
    google_ad_width = 728;   \
    google_ad_height = 90;   \
    <'+'/script>  \
    <script type="text/javascript"  \
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">  \
    <'+'/script>';

 $('head').append(adsenseCode);
}
```

- I adjusted your `.append()` call so that it will append to the document's `<head>` block.
- I broke up the `</script>` end tags to avoid confusing the browser if this code is, itself, located within a `<script>...</script>` block.  This may or may not be necessary, depending on browser versions, doctypes, and other things, but I think it's generally a good idea for safety's sake.

---

As @DarkFalcon notes in the comments, jQuery's append function may prevent scripts with external sources from being loaded.  I've experimented with this a bit, and it doesn't seem to be a problem though.  Let us know if this works or not. If it doesn't, we can explore other alternatives.

Comment: Note that according to the comments for `append`, script tags which reference external scripts will not run. I'm not sure if this is still true. Another potential issue would be if this script writes the ads by using `document.write`, which would cause the entire page to be replaced with ads.

Comment: Thank you. This code worked well when I make **var adsenseCode** one long line. Else I got syntax error.

Comment: Ah, of course you're right: the javascript string can't span multiple lines without using line-continuation markers (backslash).  I've adjusted my example accordingly.  I'm glad you got it sorted out.  Thanks for posting back your results.